# GNAT How to make first array ada program, no languages defined for this project

Tags: ada, gnat

I have Windows 10 64bit and I installed GNAT programming studio (no settings are made like java jdk) just installed. I want to make my first Ada programe in GPS GNAT programming studio.

Based on this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44166682/230513), following is `Arrayproject.adb`:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Arrayproject is

type MyArray is array (1 .. 16) of Integer;

procedure put(s: MyArray) is
    begin
    for i in s'range loop
        Put (s(i), Width =>4);
    end loop;
    new_line;
end put;

s: MyArray := (11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26);
d: MyArray := s;

begin
put_Line ("Chunks of source Array");
put(s);
put_Line ("Chunks of destination of array");
d(1 .. 4) :=s(9 .. 12);
d(5 .. 8) :=s(1 .. 4);
d(9 .. 12) :=s(13 .. 16);
d(13 .. 16) :=s(5 .. 8);
put (d);
end Arrayproject;
```

This code is compiling fine in online Ada compiler, but I do not know how to use it in GNAT programming studio. Error is coming that no languages defined for this project.

Following is khurram.gpr. Please help me making gpr and compiling.

```
Project Khurram is
for Source_Dirs use ("src");
for Object_Dir use "obj";
for Main use ("Arrayproject.adb");
end Khurram;
```

Comment: I think that error means that GPS can’t find a compiler - is your PATH set up properly?

Comment: Did you install GPS with the compiler tool chain for the windows?

Comment: Citing the original code is [required](https://stackexchange.com/legal) as a term of service.

Answer (score 7):

Define a language in your .gpr-file:

`for Languages use ("Ada");`